# Incorrect path to find templates in Laravel Homestead

Tags: laravel, homestead

I struggled for about 30m to understand what was happening here and once i found it i decided to post this and immediately an answer in case this could help people.

I'm using homestead and laravel 5.2. The machine is working up to the point where the welcome view cannot be displayed because it is not found. After looking correctly at it, i noticed that my path to the templates directory is the path of my local machine instead of the path of the homestead machine:

For example:

- /home/crazycodr/code/myapp/resources/views

instead of

- /home/vagrant/code/myapp/resources/views

Where was it getting that from? After all, the path is using __ DIR __, how could it use my local machine path?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple, i had ran:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

on my local machine which generated a local machine path. Lesson learned, never run any artisan command that could generate paths on your local machine. Creating a new item such as a model, service provider or middleware using artisan should be ok, but caching the config is not recommended at all.